# Change color of a key

Tags: java, android, colors, keyboard

I want to ask, if theres a methode to change the color of a specific key on my customkeyboard.

My current Keyboard looks like this:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RDK4.png]

But I want to highlite the current Keyboardlayout like this:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/5der9.jpg]

My current Code looks like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateInputView()
{
    kv = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);

    checkApp();

    if (name.toString().equals("com.android.browser")){
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.querty);

    }else{
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.count);
        mode = 0;
    }

    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return kv;
}

private String checkApp()
{

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    name = am.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
    Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return name;

}


@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes)
{
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(100);

    switch (primaryCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_MODE_CHANGE:
            if (mode == 1)
            {
                keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.count);
                kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);

                mode = 0;
                break;
            } else
            {
                keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.querty);
                kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
                mode = 1;
                break;
            }
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1,0);
            break;

        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            caps = !caps;
            keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;

        default:
            char code = (char) primaryCode;
            if (Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
                code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
            }
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
            break;
    }


}
```

And my keyboard xml looks like that

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:keyWidth="34%p"
      android:horizontalGap="0px"
      android:verticalGap="0px"
      android:keyHeight="40dp">

<Row>
    <Key android:keyLabel="abc" android:codes="-2" android:keyWidth="50%p"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
    <Key android:keyLabel="123" android:codes="-2" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:keyWidth="50%p"/>

</Row>

<Row>

    <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
    <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>

</Row>

<Row>

    <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
    <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>

</Row>

<Row>

    <Key android:codes="161" android:keyLabel="7" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
    <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>

</Row>

<Row>

    <Key android:codes="" android:keyLabel="" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0"/>
    <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyLabel="Del" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:isRepeatable="true"/>

</Row>
```

I hope you guys can help me.